# PHPMailer failing to send mail

Tags: php, html, smtp, phpmailer

I am trying to use PHPMailer to send data input into a contact form to another email address. I followed the [Build A PHP Contact Form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtWD_ZH9lnE&feature=youtu.be) but I cant seem to get it to work.
This is my index.php

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once 'helpers/security.php';

$errors = isset($_SESSION['errors']) ? $_SESSION['errors'] : [];
$fields = isset($_SESSION['fields']) ? $_SESSION['fields'] : [];

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Contact Form</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contact">

            <?php if(!empty($errors)): ?>
                <div class="panel">
                    <ul><li><?php echo implode('</li><li>', $errors); ?></li></ul>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <form action="contact.php" method="post">
                <label>
                    Your name *
                    <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" <?php echo isset($fields['name']) ? ' value="' . e($fields['name']) . '"' : '' ?>>
                </label>
                <label>
                    Your email address *
                    <input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" <?php echo isset($fields['email']) ? ' value="' . e($fields['email']) . '"' : '' ?>>
                </label>
                <label>
                    Your message *
                    <textarea name="message" rows="8" <?php echo isset($fields['message']) ? e($fields['message']) : '' ?>></textarea>
                </label>

                <input type="submit" value="Send">

                <p class="muted">* means a required field</p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?php

unset($_SESSION['errors']);
unset($_SESSION['fields']);

?>
```

And this is my contact.php

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once 'libs/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$errors = [];

if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['message'])) {

    $fields = [
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'message' => $_POST['message']
        ];

        foreach($fields as $field => $data) {
            if(empty($data)) {
                $errors[] = 'The ' . $field . ' field is required.';
            }
        }

        if(empty($errors)) {

            $mail = new PHPMailer;


            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

            $mail->SMTPDebug = false;

            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $mail->Username = 'email@gmail.com';
            $mail->Password =  'password';
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
            $mail->Port = 465;

            $mail->isHTML(true);

            $mail->Subject = 'Contact form submitted';
            $mail->Body = 'From: ' . $fields['name'] . ' (' . $fields['email'] . ')<p>' . $fields['message'] . '</p>';

            $mail->FromName = 'Contact';

            $mail->AddAddress('email@gmail.com', 'name');

            if($mail->send()) {
                header('Location: thanks.php');
            } else {
                $errors[] = 'Sorry, could not send email. Try again later.';
            }

        }

} else {
        $errors[] = 'Something went wrong.';
}

$_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
$_SESSION['fields'] = $fields;
header('Location: index.php')

?>
```

When I try to submit the contact form I get the error "Sorry, could not send email. Try again later." Could anyone help me figure out what is going wrong? Thanks in advance

When I used print_r($mail), it output the following:

```
2015-04-03 12:37:40 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 127.0.0.1 2015-04-03 12:37:40    CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in C:\xampp\htdocs\contact_form\libs\phpmailer\class.smtp.php on line 339
2015-04-03 12:37:40 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2015-04-03 12:37:40  SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 2015-04-03 12:37:40    SMTP connect() failed. 
PHPMailer Object ( [Version] => 5.2.9 [Priority] => 3 [CharSet] => iso-8859-1 [ContentType] => text/html [Encoding] => 8bit [ErrorInfo] => SMTP connect() failed. [From] => root@localhost [FromName] => Contact [Sender] => [ReturnPath] => [Subject] => Contact form submitted [Body] => From: Your name field (your email address field)

your message field

[AltBody] => 
[Ical] => 
[MIMEBody:protected] => From: Your name field (your email address field)
your message field

[MIMEHeader:protected] => Date: Fri, 3 Apr 2015 14:37:40 +0200 To: Name From: Contact Subject: Contact form submitted Message-ID: <9c632471cedadb7f5e7ee6687ee9d5b7@127.0.0.1> X-Priority: 3 X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.9 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/) MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 
[mailHeader:protected] => 
[WordWrap] => 0 
[Mailer] => smtp 
[Sendmail] => /usr/sbin/sendmail [UseSendmailOptions] => 1 
[PluginDir] => 
[ConfirmReadingTo] => 
[Hostname] => 
[MessageID] => 
[MessageDate] => Fri, 3 Apr 2015 14:37:40 +0200 
[Host] => smtp.gmail.com 
[Port] => 587 
[Helo] => 
[SMTPSecure] => tls 
[SMTPAuth] => 1 
[Username] => email@gmail.com 
[Password] => password 
[AuthType] => 
[Realm] => 
[Workstation] => 
[Timeout] => 300 
[SMTPDebug] => 1 
[Debugoutput] => echo 
[SMTPKeepAlive] => 
[SingleTo] => 
[SingleToArray] => Array ( ) 
[do_verp] => 
[AllowEmpty] => 
[LE] => 
[DKIM_selector] => 
[DKIM_identity] => 
[DKIM_passphrase] => 
[DKIM_domain] => 
[DKIM_private] => 
[action_function] => 
[XMailer] => 
[smtp:protected] => SMTP Object ( [Version] => 5.2.9 [SMTP_PORT] => 25 [CRLF] => [do_debug] => 1 [Debugoutput] => echo [do_verp] => [Timeout] => 300 [Timelimit] => 300 [smtp_conn:protected] => [error:protected] => Array ( ) [helo_rply:protected] => [server_caps:protected] => [last_reply:protected] => ) 
[to:protected] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => email@gmail.com [1] => Name ) ) 
[cc:protected] => Array ( ) 
[bcc:protected] => Array ( ) 
[ReplyTo:protected] => Array ( ) 
[all_recipients:protected] => Array ( [email@gmail.com] => 1 ) 
[attachment:protected] => Array ( ) 
[CustomHeader:protected] => Array ( ) 
[lastMessageID:protected] => <9c632471cedadb7f5e7ee6687ee9d5b7@127.0.0.1> 
[message_type:protected] => plain 
[boundary:protected] => Array ( [1] => b1_9c632471cedadb7f5e7ee6687ee9d5b7 [2] => b2_9c632471cedadb7f5e7ee6687ee9d5b7 [3] => b3_9c632471cedadb7f5e7ee6687ee9d5b7 ) 
[language:protected] => Array ( [authenticate] => SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. [connect_host] => SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. [data_not_accepted] => SMTP Error: data not accepted. [empty_message] => Message body empty [encoding] => Unknown encoding: [execute] => Could not execute: [file_access] => Could not access file: [file_open] => File Error: Could not open file: [from_failed] => The following From address failed: [instantiate] => Could not instantiate mail function. [invalid_address] => Invalid address [mailer_not_supported] => mailer is not supported. [provide_address] => You must provide at least one recipient email address. [recipients_failed] => SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: [signing] => Signing Error: [smtp_connect_failed] => SMTP connect() failed. [smtp_error] => SMTP server error: [variable_set] => Cannot set or reset variable: ) 
[error_count:protected] => 1 
[sign_cert_file:protected] => 
[sign_key_file:protected] => 
[sign_key_pass:protected] => 
[exceptions:protected] => ) 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\contact_form\contact.php:53) in C:\xampp\htdocs\contact_form\contact.php on line 63
```

Comment: Turn on SMTP debug and see what it tells you.

Comment: If I turn it on nothing happens. Do I have to echo it?

Comment: You should add `$mail->ErrorInfo` to your error string. Also look at [the code examples](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples) (gmail and send_file_upload) provided with PHPMailer as they're better than the example you've followed.

Comment: I changed it from ssl to tls, and changed the port from 465 to 587. I used print_r($mail) and it gave me the following error: 'OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in C:\xampp\htdocs\contact_form\libs\phpmailer\class.smtp.php on line 339' 
I added the whole output to the original post. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. I made the following changes to my contact.php

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once 'libs/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$errors = [];

if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['message'])) {

    $fields = [
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'message' => $_POST['message']
        ];

        foreach($fields as $field => $data) {
            if(empty($data)) {
                $errors[] = 'The ' . $field . ' field is required.';
            }
        }

        if(empty($errors)) {

            $mail = new PHPMailer();

            $mail->IsSMTP();

            //$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

            $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

            $mail->Host = 'aspmx.l.google.com' ;
            //$mail->Username = 'email@gmail.com';
            //$mail->Password =  'password';
            //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
            $mail->Port = 25;

            $mail->isHTML(true);

            $mail->Subject = 'Contact form submitted';
            $mail->Body = 'From: ' . $fields['name'] . ' (' . $fields['email'] . ')<p>' . $fields['message'] . '</p>';

            $mail->FromName = 'Contact';

            $mail->AddAddress('email@gmail.com', 'Name');



            if($mail->send()) {
                header('Location: thanks.php');
            } else {
                $errors[] = 'Sorry, could not send email. Try again later.';
                //print_r($mail);
            }

        }

} else {
        $errors[] = 'Something went wrong.';
}
$_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
$_SESSION['fields'] = $fields;
header('Location: index.php')

?>
```